# How to apply constant force on a Box2D body?

Tags: iphone, box2d

I am making a Box2d game for the iPhone. I need to apply a force on a body which represents my main character. The body is actually a rectangle on top of a circle connected using a revolute joint. I am using this as the skeleton for my character who is supposed to be running through the game(any suggestions or feedback on this too would be appreciated).

I need a force to be applied continuously so that it keeps him moving. What would be the best way to do this?

I am currently applying linear velocity inside the tick method.

```
_world->Step(dt, 10, 10);

if(gamestarted)
{
    b2Vec2 force = b2Vec2(6, -3);
    _bottomBody->SetLinearVelocity(force);
}
```

But will this force keep adding up and accelerate the body?

Comment: what if you are calling it in the accelerometer:didAccelerate method?

Answer (score 7):

Seems simple:

```
_bottomBody->ApplyForce(force, _bottomBody->GetPosition());
```

If you apply that force in every step the body will accelerate in the direction of the force vector.

Comment: what about inconsistency of framerate

Comment: Totally agree with @WolfLink. This is not a constant force, as frame rate is not constant.