# Box2D Gravity to specific object?

Tags: ios, box2d, gravity, physics-engine

I see everyone saying that you add gravity like so in a Box2D world:

```
b2Vec2 gravity = b2Vec2(0.0f, -10.0f);
bool doSleep = false;
world = new b2World(gravity, doSleep);
```

The thing is though, what if I want gravity only on a specific b2Body which contains userData from a CCSprite? AFAIK this will apply gravity to everything in the world which I do not want, so can someone explain to me how I can apply this gravity only to a specific b2Body?

Thanks!

**Edit1:**
Can I just do this line,

```
_bottomBody->ApplyForce(gravity, _bottomBody->GetPosition());
```

Instead of the world = new b2World... etc... Wouldn't that work with gravity only on that b2Body?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just apply a force/impulse to the specific b2Body every frame. It will emulate gravity.

```
// a procedure called every frame
void Application::on_update_world(double t)
{
  m_body_with_custom_gravity->applyForce(CUSTOM_GRAVITY * m_body_with_custom_gravity->getMass());

  m_phys_world->Step(t, VEL_ITERATIONS, POS_ITERATIONS);
}
```

A thread with a question closely related to your:
[How to apply constant force on a Box2D body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666588/how-to-apply-constant-force-on-a-box2d-body)

Comment: How so? I just would rather use the way above, is there any way to modify my code above just to apply to one object?

Comment: Your application undoubtedly has a frame loop, i.e. a procedure/method where you call b2World::step(). Inside this procedure, you need to call applyForce method for the specified body. See a code example in this answer.

Comment: My application does not have a frame loop. My app is Box2d Mixed with Cocos2d mixed with Obj C. I just use a Cocos2D game loop that gets called every possible second which means when the view gets updated. Check Edit 1 in my original post if that code would work for me.

Comment: Where does your engine call b2World::Step()? It's only a right place to apply force to your body. I remind, for the correct simulation the custom gravity force must be applied to the body before every call of the b2World::Step() method.

Comment: The box2d engine resets all forces applied to bodies in the end of b2World::Step() so the custom gravity force must be reapplied to the body before every call of the b2World::Step() method.